# How to get even groups in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I want to get a certain number of even groups based on a collection of records with varying count. How is this possible?

I'm looking for a method like `objects.in_x_even_groups(4)`

Comment: Please define "even groups". If you have 7 items and you want 3 groups, for example, do you want 3-3-1, 3-2-2 or something else? Also, are they to be kept in  order?

Comment: Yes, I should have specified the ordering. See @Max's answer below. He got close to what I was looking for...

Comment: Your comment does not help. Please edit to state precisely what you want to do.

Comment: I was specifically looking for the output from `in_groups(3, false)` ... Ordered groups within even(ish) columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume:

- the elements are to be kept in order;
- `l-s` is to be minimized, where `l` is the size of the largest group and `s` is the size of the smallest group; and
- group sizes are non-increasing.

`l-s` will be at most `1`.

```
def group_em(arr, ngroups)
  n_per_group, left_over = arr.size.divmod(ngroups)
  cum_off = 0
  ngroups.times.map do |i|
    n = n_per_group + (i < left_over ? 1 : 0)
    a = arr[cum_off, n]
    cum_off += n
    a     
  end
end
```

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
(1..7).each { |m| puts "ngroups=#{m}: #{group_em(arr, m)}" }
ngroups=1: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
ngroups=2: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
ngroups=3: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
ngroups=4: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
ngroups=5: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
ngroups=6: [[1, 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
ngroups=7: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Group your objects by their index modulo the number of groups.

```
objects.group_by.with_index { |_, i| i % num_groups }.values
```

Example:

```
objects = %w{a b c d e f g h i j k}
objects.group_by.with_index { |_, i| i % 3 }.values
# [["a", "d", "g", "j"], ["b", "e", "h", "k"], ["c", "f", "i"]]
```

This won't pad undersized groups with nil and it also will interleave your objects. So this won't work if you need consecutive objects to be in the same group.

Comment: Good answer, and happy to give you credit, but I found an easier way that handles vertical ordering per row, if you want to add that to your answer too, I will check your answer as correct `objects.in_groups(3, false)` <-- the "false" removes nil objects.

Comment: @Abram you should mark one of the `in_groups` answers as correct. I don't mind

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [`in_groups`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups) method. From the docs:

> ```
> in_groups(number, fill_with = nil)
> ```
>
> Splits or iterates over the array in `number` of groups, padding any remaining slots with `fill_with` unless it is `false`.
>
> ```
> %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).in_groups(3) {|group| p group}
> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
> ["5", "6", "7", nil]
> ["8", "9", "10", nil]
> ```

Comment: This is rails only

Comment: That is my fault. I asked for ruby, but rails worked for me. I upvoted this one, but I'll give Cary the check/tick since he actually answered the question I asked.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for `in_groups_of`:

https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

```
array = %w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
array.in_groups_of(3) {|group| p group}
=>
["1", "2", "3"]
["4", "5", "6"]
["7", "8", "9"]
["10", nil, nil]
```

Comment: This is incorrect unfortunately. I don't need groups of 3, I need X even groups of ?.